# Node.js On Non-Root Android

Tags: android, node.js

As the question title states, can I install `node.js` on Android without root? I have a couple terminal emulator apps and at least one of them has `BusyBox`, `git`, and `adp`, among other things, though I am severely limited in what I can do with them. For example, I can not just `git clone` the `node.js` source code, as "No auth methods c[an] be used". I can download the `node.js` source code, but it seems to be under the "system_server" user as soon as it's downloaded, which I assume is the root user or very close. I am able to unpack it, but unable to run the `configure` executable in this directory, I assume because it is owned by root as soon as it is downloaded.

Am I trying the right approach here? I have heard about [anode](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode), but its wiki is empty and whatever instructions it has are confusing and do not say whether I need to be root. Everything else I have seen tells me I have to have a rooted Android to install `node.js`, but I hate to give up after so much effort.

Answer (score 0):

## Instead installing node.js on the android device, try [jxcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore).

You can download an android executable binary from its download page, and execute it from the terminal emulator. Remember to set up exec flags.

---

EDIT: jxcore seems no longer under development.

Comment: The links that you have mentioned are broken

Comment: There is a git repo at https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore but nowadays there are nodejs packages avaliable for most situations